# Analyzing ABn test when normality is not met

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, wilcoxon-signed-rank, ab-test

I'm analyzing an unpaired A/B/C/D test to assess whether the mean or median of population B/C/D is higher than the one of A. 
As shown from the left plot the normality distribution cannot be assumed. This is because out of the total ~48000 observations only 540 are non-zero values.
Even if I remove the 0s the remaining 540 observations don't show normality as we can see on the plot on the right.

[image]

Based on this, I'm applying a Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test (instead of T-test) to assess statistical significance via the P-value. On top, I'm also applying Bonferroni correction to the p-value threshold in order to account for the multiple comparisons.

My concern is that the distribution is extremely skewed. Is there anything else I can do to ensure the conclusions are robust?

Comment: Can you give some more information? What kind of outcome does your test generate? Are you interested in the mean outcome, or in the median, or in some quantile?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Your graph lacks a horizontal scale, and so is not very helpful. Can you say how large are your datasets? values rounded to how many places? typical sample means? typical sample medians?

Comment: Does the graph just show all data points lumped together, instead of breaking out the As and the Bs? It's a histogram, I take it? How many points are in the region we can see vs other points farther to the right on the x axis? How many data points are there? Note that you don't need the data to be normally distributed for the t-test, a common misconception, you only need a large enough sample that the sample mean is pretty close to normal. With highly skewed data, you'll need more data than if the distribution were symmetric, but if you have a million points then you're probably still good.

Comment: as @SheridanGrant mentioned what you care is that the distribution of sample means is normally distributed which could well be true by central limit theorem. generate bootstrap samples of your group means and plot/analyse the distribution of sample means - they may well be normal.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I've edited my question to provide more clarity of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Consider samples of size $n=1000$ from $\mathsf{Beta}(.01,1)$ and $\mathsf{Beta}(.02,1),$ respectively. Then respective population means
are $\mu_x \approx 0.01$ and $\mu_y \approx 0.02$, and population medians
are distinct, but both near $0.$

```
qbeta(.5, .01,1); qbeta(.5, .02,1)
[1] 7.888609e-31  # pop median of x
[1] 8.881784e-16  # pop median of y
```

However, in any real application, data must be rounded to *some* number
of decimal places. So in practice, sample means may not estimate
population means well, and sample medians will likely both be exactly $0.$

```
set.seed(1234)
x = round(rbeta(1000, .01,1),6)
y = round(rbeta(1000, .02,1),6)

mean(x); mean(y)
[1] 0.01314054
[1] 0.01496366
median(x); median(y)
[1] 0
[1] 0
quantile(x, .75)
75% 
  0 
quantile(y, .75)
  75% 
1e-06
```

These data challenge even the legendary robustness of the two-sample
t test, which finds no difference in population means:

```
t.test(x, y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -0.50169, df = 1946, p-value = 0.6159
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.008950012  0.005303760
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
0.01314054 0.01496366
```

Moreover, the two-sample Wilcoxon test must somehow find
the 'locations' of the samples, even though both sample medians
are 0 (and even both upper quartiles are very nearly 0).
The Wilcoxon test, as implemented in R, does find a significant difference in locations. Because I have no idea how this is
accomplished, I would want to explore further before knowing
how much faith to have in the resulting P-value.

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 438400, p-value = 5.825e-12
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.476138e-05 -3.993408e-05
sample estimates:
difference in location 
         -3.576837e-05
```

Unless or until you can provide more insight into the data than you
have done so far, I will have to leave an Answer as unresolved at
this point.

*Note:* For what it's worth, a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
also finds a difference between the two populations (along with a warning about ties):

```
ks.test(x,y)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y
D = 0.122, p-value = 6.871e-07
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(x, y) : p-value will be approximate 
                   in the presence of ties
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I 've edited my question to help provide more context to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With 48,000 observations, even if the data is pretty highly skewed the t test might do okay. As nba2020 suggested, you could bootstrap your sample and observe the distribution of means, though this can't guarantee anything. BruceET's example uses only 1000 observations from a *very* skewed distribution--I'm not sure your data are quite as nefarious.

To reiterate, because your edit still has this issue: the t test **does not** assume the *data* are normally distributed; a large enough sample size that the asymptotic normality of the sample mean "kicks in" is sufficient. The Wilcoxon rank-sum test does not test differences in means or medians except under somewhat restrictive assumptions on the shapes of the distributions. It will tell you if the distributions are different, but beyond that it can be hard to interpret.